# How can I examine the inheritance hierarchy of my c# application at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given a class like this:

```
public class A : B<C> {...}
```

Assume that I know how to find A's class type using reflection.  How can I figure out at run time what base class it extends (in this case B)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var a = new A();

Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().BaseType);
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I totally couldn't find that BaseType property until just after I'd posted the question. :-P